# Adobe premiere cc 2017: Archive (clip) After rendering, gets too long, why?

Tags: premiere

Adobe premiere cc 2017: Archive (clip)
 After rendering, gets too long, why?

1-I download the file of size 5MB www.youtube.com/watch?v=j648ZWxh5UE of Youtube
2-Import for TIMELINE
3-I do not do anything (no cut, no insert, no effect)
4-Control M
5-Set with the same parameters as the original
6-Command to render.
What is the result? Generates a very large final file, 27MB (changed from 5MB to 27MB)!
Can anyone explain? It should not be a file of the same size as the original, because it was not cut, nor spliced, nor put effect and the same parameters of the original were kept in audio and video.
I am a beginner of ADOBE PREMIERE. Can anybody help me? I would be very grateful. Yes, I really want to thank MoritzLost, he helped me a lot with a previous question. hug

Comment: Match same parameters only means to match the image dimension and frame rate. You still need to select an export codec/preset. Which preset did you pick?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, when you want to export it your desired format(for example : H.264 format,*H.264 is also known as MPEG-4 AVC. Developed for use in high definition systems such as HDTV, Blu-ray and for low resolution devices*) you have to customize the export settings.

The two factors which determine file size are **program duration and bitrate**.  The longer your program is, the larger the file will be.

But the bitrate is, Choosing Uncompressed will have the highest bitrate possible.  Choosing an MPEG variant (MPEG1, 2 or H.264) will allow you to lower the bitrate (and hence create a smaller file) while still achieving acceptable quality.

Under the export settings you are getting the Preset.You can select a preset the way you want it.But keep in mind choosing the correct Preset with the **FPS(Frames per Second)**.Choosing a lower FPS would reduce the quality of the video.

In this issue it's recommended to use the resolution of the Original video(which is 720p) in the preset.You can change the FPS and check for the quality.**[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-elements/using/viewing-clip-properties.html)** is how you check the **FPS** of a video in Premiere Pro.

Choose the exact resolution if you want to get the same file size Under the video tab in the export window.Change the level (which constrains encoding parameters bitrate range and FPS)and you can get the actual file size by changing it.You will see the estimated file size below. **This is not recommended** as it reduces the quality.

You can customize the export settings same as the original and you will get the file size you mentioned which is 27MB.That's how you got 27MB for the file size.

Note: Codecs do the magic!.